# Adding custom headers in apache based on post request parameters

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have an API (POST) hosted on apache server, which I want to proxy it to another server. I have done it by using ProxyPass feature. Following is the excerpt:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain 
  ServerAlias *.mydomain 
  ProxyPass /myAPI/ redirectedServer/redirectedAPI/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

How ever, I want to add custom headers to the request, based on the value set in one of the parameters in POST request. For e.g. sample requests can be

```
{"key":"value1"}, {"key":"value2"}
```

based on the value of "key" coming in the POST request, I want to add different custom headers 
  `{"token":{"value_for_value1"}},{"token":{"value_for_value2 "}}`

I was checking the documentation of ReWriteRule/ReWriteMap, but couldn't understand as to how to do it. 
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Are the keys different post parameters or are they part of JSON data posted in a single POST parameter?

Comment: @Capsule the key via which the header value is determined, is a part of incoming post request itself.

Comment: Yeah but how does the whole POST request look like? Please add a detailed view of the HTTP request.